# Regular expression to match line continuations that begin with whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract "entries" from a text file using a regular expression. Each line of the file is a separate entry unless the line begins with whitespace, in which case that line is a continuation of the previous line.

Example:

```
import re

INPUT = """\
This is entry 1.
This
 is
  entry 2.
And this is entry 3.
This
 is
 entry
 4."""

OUTPUT = ["This is entry 1.",
          "This\n is\n  entry 2.",
          "And this is entry 3.",
          "This\n is\n entry\n 4."]

# What should the pattern be?
PATTERN = re.compile("(.+)(?=\n|$)")

assert PATTERN.findall(INPUT) == OUTPUT
```

What should `PATTERN` be to match all the entries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think figured it out.

The trick is "`.` (which doesn't match newlines) or a newline followed by whitespace".

```
PATTERN = re.compile(r"(?:.|\n\s)+")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [92]: re.findall(r'(.+(?:\n\s.*)*)\n?', INPUT)
Out[92]: 
['This is entry 1.',
 'This\n is\n  entry 2.',
 'And this is entry 3.',
 'This\n is\n entry\n 4.']

In [93]: OUTPUT == re.findall(r'(.+(?:\n\s.*)*)\n?', INPUT)
Out[93]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex I tested in Java

```
^\S[.\s\w\r\n]*?(?=\n\S|\Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can rely on the first letter of the sentence being capitalized, I think a good way to go about this is the following regex:

```
re.findall(r'\w[\w\s]+?\.', INPUT)
```

In practice, using your value of `INPUT`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w[\w\s]+?\.', INPUT)
['This is entry 1.', 'This\n is\n  entry 2.', 'And this is entry 3.', 'This\n is\n entry\n 4.']
```

The regex I wrote has a `\w` right before the `[\w\s]+?` in order to ensure that each match begins at the beginning of the sentence, rather than the whitespace before.

Answer (score 0):

```
OUTPUT = re.sub("[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]+", " ", INPUT).split("\n");
```

#### See [this demo](http://ideone.com/ToC2yj).

Comment: @Jon-Eric - I have updated my answer with new code - Please let me know if demo works for you...